# What is postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

What is postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1 ? what is the difference of postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1 and postgis

```
sudo apt-get install postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

which one enable the postgis plugin of a postgres database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postgis` package comes from Fedora/RHEL. `rpm -qip` on the package will report `Packager: Fedora` and `yum info postgis` reports `From repo   : updates`. It installs PostGIS for the Fedora/RHEL-packaged PostgreSQL, which is in a package named `postgresql`.

The `postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1` package comes from PGDG, the PostgreSQL Development Group, at http://yum.postgresql.org/ . It's an extension repository that adds access to newer PostgreSQL versions than Fedora/RHEL include for any given version. The postgis packages from that repository install PostGIS for the associated PostgreSQL release. So this package installs PostGIS 2.1 for PostgreSQL 9.4 from PGDG, for the PostgreSQL package named `postgresql-9.4`.

You should install the PostGIS package that corresponds to the PostgreSQL package you have installed and are using. If you have enabled PGDG packages then that's very likely the PGDG PostgreSQL, so you should install `postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1`.